# Problem upgrading a subscription on google pay. When they first subscribe everything works but when they try to upgrade, it does not work

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

So, basically, I get an error when I try to upgrade a subscription using google pay billingclient api. When the user subscribes, it works fine but then if they want to upgrade their subscription it throws an error. The error is "user is not eligible for this purchase" I have tried to contact google support to get suggestions regarding this problem but I have not heard back from them yet.

It might be a problem from within my code so I am going to paste the code and I am open to suggestions as I have been working on resolving this error for a while now.

BillingClient version is 4.0.0

And I testing it in a closed test

The code is :

```
private void subscribe(SkuDetails skuDetails,String accountId,String profileId,int is_up,String token ){
        int code =billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS).getResponseCode();
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams;

        if(is_up ==0){
            billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                            .setObfuscatedAccountId(accountId)
                            .setObfuscatedProfileId(profileId)
                            .build();
        }else if(is_up==1){
            billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setObfuscatedAccountId(accountId)
                    .setObfuscatedProfileId(profileId)
                   .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                            .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(token.trim())
                            .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                            .build())
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                    .setVrPurchaseFlow(false)
                    .build();
        }else {
            billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setObfuscatedAccountId(accountId)
                    .setObfuscatedProfileId(profileId)
                   .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                            .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(token.trim())
                            .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                            .build())
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                    .setVrPurchaseFlow(true)
                    .build();
        }

        int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(getActivity(), billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();
    }
```

```
  @Override
        public void do_payment(String token_id, String order_id,String  prd_id,String account_id,String profile_id,int is_up,String token,String  callback) {
            callBacktoWeb =callback;
            if(bBillingClientReady){
                displaySubs(order_id,prd_id,account_id,profile_id,is_up,token);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"bBillingClient not Ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

```
private void displaySubs(String order_id,String prd_id,String accountId,String profileId,int is_up,String token){
        mOrderId =order_id;
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(prd_id);
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                     List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        if(billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                            if(skuDetailsList!=null){
                                for (SkuDetails skuDetail:skuDetailsList){

                                    subscribe(skuDetail,accountId,profileId,is_up,token);
                                }
                            }else {
                                Logger.d(PTAG,"skuDetailsList size:"+skuDetailsList.size());
                            }
                        }else {
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```